# exporting lwjgl program with seperate resources

Tags: java, export, lwjgl

I'm trying to export a game I made with lwjgl to a jar file, and I have used jarsplice to create a fat jar. My problem is it keeps coming up with a:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/shaders/basic.vs (No such file or
>   directory)

The shaders are in a separate folder (outside of the src folder) called 'res'.
[image: d]

The jar file has the res folder inside of it so I'm not sure why It can't find it.

I'm using eclipse FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the res folder inside of the src folder and use >Object.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/shaders/basic.vs")
instead i reads the path to where ever the folder is located on the file system.